# How to have an empty post title and content when creating a new WordPress post via the front-end

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

My aim is to insert a new draft post into the database via a custom front-end form I've created. I need the post title and content to be empty. Is this possible?

I've tried the following which doesn't work:

```
$post_data = array(
    'post_title'    => '',
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_content'  => '',
    'post_status'   => 'draft',
    'post_author'   => 1
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
```

**Note:** You can create a new post using the back-end editor with empty title and content so I am wondering how they guys at WordPress do it.

Comment: Do you have any errors ? `wp_insert_post( $post_data, true );` should return some :)

Comment: Yes, I get a "Content, title and excerpt" are empty. Var dumping: object(WP_Error)#34 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["empty_content"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(38) "Content, title, and excerpt are empty." } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not insert a blank post with `wp_insert_post`, Wordpress will prevent it with `wp_insert_post_empty_content` hook, you can see it in the source code : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

The only way to do it is to overpass this hook with a custom function

Here is an example ([source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28021/how-to-publish-a-post-with-empty-title-and-empty-content))

```
add_filter('pre_post_title', 'wpse28021_mask_empty');
add_filter('pre_post_content', 'wpse28021_mask_empty');
function wpse28021_mask_empty($value)
{
    if ( empty($value) ) {
        return ' ';
    }
    return $value;
}

add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'wpse28021_unmask_empty');
function wpse28021_unmask_empty($data)
{
    if ( ' ' == $data['post_title'] ) {
        $data['post_title'] = '';
    }
    if ( ' ' == $data['post_content'] ) {
        $data['post_content'] = '';
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a filter in WordPress core that can be used to prevent this.

```
wp_insert_post_empty_content
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post_empty_content/

Which you should be able to use like:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content', '__return_false' );

$post = wp_insert_post( $post_args );
```